# Searching for an expression in a very long String in Java

Tags: java, string

My String containing a text file of 50 MB.
I got my String like this:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("wiki.txt", "r");
FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, 1024*50);
byte[] b = new byte[1024*50];
buffer.get(b);
String wiki = new String(b);
```

I get a String expression that can contain multiple words, and I need to return an answer if this expression is in my wiki String (the big String) or not.
The action works good for about 1% of the String(from the beginning of the String), and when the phrase I'm looking for is in the middle or end of the String, the answer I get for the following code is a false:

```
System.out.println(wiki.contains(strToCheck));
System.out.println(wiki.indexOf(strToCheck, 0));
System.out.println(wiki.matches("(?i).*"+strToCheck+".*"));
```

Does anyone know why this happens?
Or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Aren't you setting your buffer/byte Array/String to only be able to see the first 50KB, not MB?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494772/bad-to-use-very-large-strings-java for information (not an exact duplicate, but pretty close) - Specifically, there's mention of a MAX_INT size limit for strings

Comment: You're mapping 50 *kilo*bytes. You probably should be mapping 50 *Mega*bytes? (Does it makes sense to create 50 MB Strings is another issue, but...)

Comment: Because I have to use this String number of times, so I thought keeping it in memory as String.
Should I use MappedByteBuffer differently? And not convert it to String?

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry to say it but  1024*50 in not 50M. It is 50K. 
It seems that you are reading 0.1% of your file and then searching in it.

Comment: I guess it was my mistake.
You can write to me how I define the size of 50 MB? Thank you.

Comment: 50*1024*1024. But PLEASE do not do this! Do not read 50M into RAM. Read the file chunk-by-chunk. Use BufferedReader, iterate over it, read line-by-line and search into it. But this solution does not support multiline strings. You can also use NIO: FileChannel and CharBuffer. Pay attention that CharBuffer implements CharSequence and `Pattern.matcher()` accepts `CharSequence` too, so you can match content of file directly without creating strings.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, 1024*1024*50);
```

because `50 MB = 1024*1024*50, 50kb = 1024 * 50`, 1MB = 1024 kb`

Comment: Provided, the memory is in the GByte range, it should be no problem to read 50 MByte. Another approach would be sorted index collection which stores the offsets of words. This would help to start the string search more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Occam's razor: `strToCheck` is NOT in `wiki`.

Comment: or rather, `strToCheck` is not in the first 0.1% of `wiki` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be performing searches in the String, you can consider implementing the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and buffering your reads of the original String so that the entire string is not loaded into memory.