# How to read Epub file Smothlly and set Horizontally webview

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am trying to open an epub file from my android app using Epub Library .  I have done Follwing things in this App:
1. Save the ebook file in Internal/External storage  and also getting the correct path of the Book
2.   getting the Content of entire book and store in on String means all books content in one String 
3. Save the All images and Css file in Local stroge of phone and replace  with  same  html  tag of book
4.   After that book set in webview (Use the custom webview for that)

Issue:
1.  Loading time is too long 
2.  Interlink is not working of Book(Example click on 4 chapter of book)
3.  text is not copied form the Custom Web view

Answer (score 0):

It is [not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494772/bad-to-use-very-large-strings-java) to store the whole book in one string.

You should use some library to make things simpler and efficient.
Here are some:

https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android

https://github.com/mertakdut/EpubParser

http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib

Comment: thanks for writting here  I have one demand  i don't want  use any Reader to open  epub  book, like Folio reader skypub reader etc  . i jus want to provide custom solution

Comment: can you please check my code from this Link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a9602834eb22fa40e8e14edca5b5417220180314053714/a46cf9